# How do I automate a remote login with a bash script

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to automate a remote login and I wrote the following bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
PWD=abc
kinit -f user@domain.com
expect "Password for user@domain.com: "
send "$PWD\n"
ssh -x user@dom.com
interact
cd user/user
```

My understanding being that "expect" is waiting for the terminal to output something and "interact" should give control of the logged-in terminal to the user. Why doesn't this script work?

Comment: Since you are using ssh anyway, you should look into ssh keys and ssh_agent.  No need for a password then.

Comment: Completely mis-using `expect`.    Type the command `autoexpect ssh -x user@dom.com`, then do the login manually, and do whatever else you want.  When you  exit, you will have `script.exp`.  Edit that file as needed to do what you want.

Comment: take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you are more comfortable with shell syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way to mix shell and expect code. You can't just invoke expect commands from the shell, you need to launch an expect process.

Something like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
export PWD=abc
expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    spawn kinit -f user@domain.com
    expect "Password for user@domain.com: "
    send "$env(PWD)\r"
    expect "this is some prompt you see after running kinit: edit this string"
    send " ssh -x user@dom.com\r"
    expect "this is the pattern for the remote prompt: edit this string"
    send "cd user/user\r"
    interact
END_EXPECT
```